# Space Occupied By Other Files And Folders On Hard Drive

Tags: macos, time-machine, hard-drive, virtualbox

I have been using VirtualBox to create a virtual machine to run Windows 8 on and after deleting the virtual drives and virtualbox due to having issues with Windows 8, I am missing a lot of memory from my hard drive. I currently also have 72GB of backups on my Hard Drive that I did not create, any ideas on how to get rid of them?

[image]

When I view my Hard Drive contents via Disk Inventory X it comes up that I have nearly 99GB of space occupied by other files that not even Disk Inventory X can identify!

[image]

Area of other files:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you attempted to empty the trash after removing the VM? Alternately, I believe that VirtualBox keeps its data at "~/VirtualBox VMs". Removing that folder may help you to reclaim drive space.

Here's more info on [TimeMachine's local snapshots](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4878). If you'd like to disable that feature, you can use these commands to perform that action:

```
sudo tmutil disablelocal
```

Here's how you can re-enable local snapshots:

```
sudo tmutil enablelocal
```

Here's how to take a snapshot:

```
tmutil snapshot
```

Comment: The removal of localsnapshots worked!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit different issue, but I also had a huge chunk of *Space Occupied By Other Files And Folders On Hard Drive* on my external disk. I found the culprit by using [OmniDiskSweeper](http://www.omnigroup.com/more) with root priveleges, as explained [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23366295#23367447).

That means: `sudo /Applications/OmniDiskSweeper.app/Contents/MacOS/OmniDiskSweeper`

In this case it was files in the trash bin, which for some reason were not deleted when emptying it. The following command then solved my problem ([source](http://www.cnet.com/news/force-empty-that-stubborn-trash-bin-in-os-x/)):

`sudo rm -rf /Volumes/ExternalHD/.Trashes`